# SQL to Eloquent ORM

Tags: sql, sql-server, orm, laravel, eloquent

I have a SQL query which I wish to use in my Laravel application.
The SQL query is like:

```
SELECT status, count(status) AS num
FROM event_businesses
WHERE event_id = ?
GROUP BY status
ORDER BY status ASC
```

and what I have till now is

```
$event_businesses = EventBusiness::select('status')
                    ->where('event_id', '=', $event_id)
                    ->groupBy('status')
                    ->orderBy('status', 'asc')->get();
```

I really don't get where can I add the `count(status) as num` aggregate to my ORM query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to do this:

```
$event_businesses = EventBusiness::select(DB::raw('status as status, count(status) as count'))
                    ->where('event_id', '=', $event_id)
                    ->groupBy('status')
                    ->orderBy('status', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: Hi Antonia, this works. But is there any way via avoiding the DB::raw?

Comment: As far as I know Laravel is still not supporting aggregate functions on result columns. But you can use aggregate on your whole result set: `$users = DB::table('users')->count();`

Comment: It's possible to create SQL injection points in raw queries.  It's better to have the sql builder build out your queries for you for that reason.  In this case though, there isn't any chance of an injection attack because you aren't using DB::raw to insert any variables.

Comment: Nowadays you can use Eloquent's `selectRaw()`, `whereRaw()`, `orderByRaw()` and `havingRaw()` methods to safely cast raw queries with parameter bindings. Details under "Raw Methods": https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions